# Reduce code duplication using javascript oop

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a javascript code which contains more number of functions. inside each functions code looks similar. Is there any way to reduce and optimize the code using javascript oop. So my script goes like this.

```
function cal_a() {
    var a_list = [];
  function fetch_dom() {
    var a = document.getElementById("pOne");
    a.innerHTML = "Hello";
    a_list.push("Hello");
  }
  fetch_dom();
}
function cal_b() {
    var b_list = [];
  function fetch_dom() {
    var b = document.getElementById("pTwo");
    b.innerHTML = "World";
    b_list.push("World");
  }
  fetch_dom();
}
cal_a();
cal_b();
//..
//..
//..
//cal_z();
```

HTML code looks

```
<p id="pOne"></p>
<p id="pTwo"></p>
```

Please pardon me if the question is wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need that IIFE `fetch_dom` ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, pull out the common parts and make a function which returns a function.

```
function make_cal(elem_id, text) {
    return function() {
        var list = [];
      function fetch_dom() {
        var b = document.getElementById(elem_id);
        b.innerHTML = text;
        list.push(text);
      }
      fetch_dom();
    }
}

let cal_a = make_cal("pOne", "Hello");
let cal_b = make_cal("pTwo", "World");
```

Comment: I'm just curious, why create many instances of a function where one can do the job?

Comment: Im making the assumption he doesn't want to change the method signature of his original methods

Comment: No, this is rather *currying* than a *factory*, although terminology is rather a minor thing here

Comment: @JonasW. no for what? You mean currying doesn't create copy of a function?

Comment: `Might be called a factory pattern.` <- not really

Answer (score 0):

I have to say the list doesn't do anything here

```
function cal(id, text) {
  var list = [];
  function fetch_dom() {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.innerHTML = text;
    list.push(text);
  }
  fetch_dom();
}

cal('id', 'text');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fetchDom` is better to be placed on object constructor:

```
function Cal(elClass, text) {
  this.list = [];
  this.elClass = elClass;
  this.text = text;
}

Cal.prototype.fetchDom = function() {
  var el = document.getElementById(this.elClass);
  el.innerHTML = this.text;
  this.list.push(el);
};

var calA = new Cal("pOne", "Hello");
var calB = new Cal("pTwo", "World");

calA.fetchDom();
calB.fetchDom();
```

Then you can access your lists by:

```
calA.list;
calB.list;
```